# GROUP BY affects joined table even if it isn't grouped by an attr. in the other table?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

[image: Relevant section of ERD]

Hello. For the most part I understand how this query works, except for the GROUP BY clause. It's pretty much turning every row into its own group and then the HAVING clause eliminates any group (units) that has prerequisite units. But how does the GROUP BY know to also group pr.unitcode along with u.unitcode? Is that implied by the join condition? Because I don't understand how else it would be able to know how to count the has_prereq_of column for the unitcode in each group otherwise, since it is an attribute in the prereq (pr) table.

Im sorry if the question is a bit hard to understand, it's really conceptual and I struggled to turn my confusion about the query into words.

*Q2. Display unitcode and unitname for units that do not have prerequisite.*

```
SELECT u.unitcode, unitname
  FROM unit u LEFT OUTER JOIN prereq pr ON u.unitcode = pr.unitcode  
  GROUP BY u.unitcode, unitname
  HAVING count(has_prereq_of) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

First the tables are pulled and joined together. From there the rows are grouped. Then they are filtered by `HAVING`. I think you need to think of the grouping happening on a set that was constructed prior to the `GROUP BY` rather than thinking of the individual tables.

Comment: I'm sorry I lost you when you said to think of grouping happening on a set constructed prior to group by.